# How to force Java compiler to error if @Override is unnecessary

Tags: java, eclipse

I've removed an unused method from an interface, and expected javac and Eclipse to complain about the fact that my implementing class still claims to override it:

```
@Override    
public void thisMethodNoLongerOverridesAnything() {}
```

However, I don't get an error or even a warning.

Is there a way to configure javac or Eclipse to complain in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [API doc of @Override](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html)

> If a method is annotated with this annotation type compilers are
>   **required to generate an error message** unless at least one of the
>   following conditions hold:
>
> - The method does override or implement a method declared in a supertype.
> - The method has a signature that is override-equivalent to that of any public method declared in Object.

So either your mothod still overrides something, or you've found a bug in both javac and eclipse, which I doubt.

Comment: I thinks its more likely just a bug in eclipse, there is nothing that suggests is has to be a bug in both. If I manually compile it then it reports the error correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Errors will come definitely.

interface A{
    void funA();
    }

```
class Test implements A{
@Override
public void funA(){

}
@Override
public void B(){

}
}
```

Errors: The method B() of type Test must override or implement a supertype method

```
Sugessions: create B() in supertype A 
            remove Override annotation
```

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:

`Properties > Java Compiler > Errors/Warnings`

The `@Override` annotation is under `Annotations` and ignored by default.

EDIT: Just re-read the question. You want to be warned if you have an unnecessary `@Override` and not when you are missing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JDK 1.5 the @Override annotation is ignored.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619036/override-annotation-in-jdk-1-6) (-> it can be also that the JDK Compliance in the eclipse preferences is set to 1.5) .